# Local notifications not working (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, localnotification

I am looking to fire local notifications. I have tried to create this and I was successful, there were no errors but when I run the app in the simulator local notifications don't execute

code in `app delegate`

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge | .Sound, categories: nil))

  // play default sound
    return true
}
```

and the `view controller`

```
class TechByteSchedulingViewController:UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func DateChosen(sender: UIButton) {
    func sendNotification(sender: UIButton) {
        var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date
        localNotification.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
        localNotification.alertBody = "check out your daily byte"
        localNotification.alertAction = "Open"
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

        func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    }
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
            }

}
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {


}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: i don't see the code for the LocalNotification

Comment: @Lamar here is the code

Comment: Refer this simple [example](https://www.topcoder.com/blog/notifications-in-ios-8-using-swift/) or this [one](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/)

Comment: I post some answer for you

Comment: [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification) has been deprecated. Take a look at [this Swift 3 example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45247943/4754881) for local notifications with [UNUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter).

Answer (score 1):

Base on what I see you implement some function inside of the ButtonAction function which is wrong... you should implement the **sendNotfication**function outside of **ButtonAction** then called it inside of **ButtonAction**

```
class TechByteSchedulingViewController:UIViewController  {

   @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

  @IBAction func DateChosen(sender: UIButton) {
    self.sendNotification()
  }

    func sendNotification() {
    var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date
    localNotification.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
    localNotification.alertBody = "check out your daily byte"
    localNotification.alertAction = "Open"
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
 }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }

    }
```