# Using UNUserNotificationCenter to support iOS 10 rich notifications, but the notification never shows up. It only sounds the alert

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

Not sure, what's missing, but I'm stuck with a weird problem!!!

Notification sounds, but isn't displayed.

I have registered the app to only display alerts and sounds, and strangely it never is displayed. I can see that the notification is added successfully. But, there seems to be something trivial that I'm not able to comprehend.

Even removing the notification works.

```
import Foundation
import NotificationCenter
import UserNotifications

class NotificationManager: NSObject {

    private let categoryIdentifier = "notificationCategory"

    private var toDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

    private enum actionIdentifier : String {
        case openApp = "openApp"
        case playMusic = "playMusic"
    }

    // MARK: - Register for notifications

    func registerForNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler { notificationSettings in
                switch notificationSettings.authorizationStatus {
                case .NotDetermined:
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Alert, .Sound]) { (granted, error) in
                        // Enable or disable features based on authorization
                        if granted {
                            print("Access requested and was granted for sending notifications")
                            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().setNotificationCategories([])
                            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
                            self.setupNotificationActions()
                        } else {
                            print("Access requested and was denied for sending notifications")
                            print(error?.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                case .Denied:
                    print("Notifications are turned off!!")
                break // nothing to do, pointless to go on
                case .Authorized:
                    self.setupNotificationActions()
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Nothing to do here
            print("iOS 9 says, Let's get started...")
            self.setupNotificationActions()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Setup notification actions

    private func setupNotificationActions() {

        // Initialize and specify the notification actions
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let openAppAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: actionIdentifier.openApp.rawValue, title: "Open App", options: [.AuthenticationRequired, .Foreground])
            let playMusicAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: actionIdentifier.playMusic.rawValue, title: "Play Music", options: [])
            let notificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryIdentifier, actions: [openAppAction, playMusicAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [.CustomDismissAction])

            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().setNotificationCategories([notificationCategory])
        } else {
            // Specify the notification actions
            let openAppAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            openAppAction.identifier = actionIdentifier.openApp.rawValue
            openAppAction.title = "Open App"
            openAppAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
            openAppAction.destructive = false

            let playMusicAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            playMusicAction.identifier = actionIdentifier.playMusic.rawValue
            playMusicAction.title = "Play Music"
            playMusicAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
            playMusicAction.destructive = false
            playMusicAction.authenticationRequired = false

            // Specify the category related to the above actions
            let notificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
            notificationCategory.identifier = categoryIdentifier
            notificationCategory.setActions([openAppAction, playMusicAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
            notificationCategory.setActions([playMusicAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)

            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: NSSet(object: notificationCategory) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
//            if (notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationType.None){
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
//            }
        }
    }
```

And, in AppDelegate...

`private let notificationManager = NotificationManager()`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    notificationManager.registerForNotifications(application)
}
```

Comment: Is your app in foreground when you are testing notification?

Comment: Nope. It isn't.

Comment: Try doing this: clear all existing delivered notifications and then showing the new one.

Comment: @prabodhprakash It's the same!! :(

Comment: @matt. I'm checking. let me see.

Comment: @matt. Before I delve more into your code. Is it okay, if I use a single instance of `UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()` throughout the app?

Comment: @matt. I've gone through your code, and implemented quite a bit of logic from yours. But, there is no difference. Actually after the updated code found above, I don't get an alert at all. No display, no sound. But, I can see that there is a notification added to the `UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter`

Comment: @matt. crossed messages!! But, thanks for getting back. Also, I picked up a few code writing etiquettes from your example! :)

Comment: Is there a way that I can only download your local notification example from GitHub? I don't see a way of doing it

Comment: Thanks @matt. I was able to download your project, and run it on my device. And, was able to then tweak mine accordingly, and make it work finally!! :) Thanks again..

Comment: This seems to be a delegate issue. But, I still can't comprehend the issue of only the sound going off!!

Comment: @matt, although this is unrelated, I'd want you to ask a question. Based on your example, I tried implementing `NotificationContentExtension`. But, as I'm still on `Swift 2.3`, I'm having a problem. `Type 'NotificationViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UNNotificationContentExtension'` Can't this live side-by-side with `Swift 2.3` ?

Comment: @matt The original problem is solved, thanks to your simple example. And, I'm able to implement a media attachment to my notification, as well. However, no luck with the NotificationContentExtension. :(

Comment: No worries. Was wondering if you had an answer, because you might have already worked on Swift 2.2/2.3.. refrained from posting an answer, as I'm still curious about how only the alert sound went off but wasn't displayed!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713605/getting-local-notifications-to-show-while-app-is-in-foreground-swift-3

Comment: @matt. This is related to your example you've suggested. I can see that your image in the notification comes off good. I'm not mentioning the content extension, its the one in the original notification. In my case, I use artwork from music library, and no matter what resolution I use, its the same cropped picture. How can I have the full image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate should be assigned correctly. Although, I wasn't able to zero in on why this happened, below changes ensured that notifications went through.

AppDelegate,

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    private let notificationManager = NotificationManager()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
    notificationManager.registerForNotifications()

    }
}
```

Insert the delegate methods in AppDelegate, itself.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever are you sending rich notification be sure about payload, must contain     "mutable-content": 1,

payload like,

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Test Rich Notification",
    "mutable-content": 1,
    "badge": "1"
  },
  "mediaUrl": "https://www.awaragroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/it-specialist.jpg",
  "mediaType": "jpg"
}
```