# How to show firebase notifications when application is in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase for push notification. I want to show a notification to the user when the application is in the foreground.

Notifications are working fine when the application is closed. But I want to display a stock iOS notification banner even if the application is active.

I have referred below link:

[Displaying a stock iOS notification banner when your app is open and in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852870/displaying-a-stock-ios-notification-banner-when-your-app-is-open-and-in-the-fore/40756060#40756060)

I want to show notification exactly the same way as shown in above link.

I have already implemented these two methods:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler(.alert)
    }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

      completionHandler()
}
```

Can someone please give me a sample of code for showing push notifications when the application is in the foreground?

Comment: @Sh_Khan That I know but how can I achieved that?

Comment: Tried to send a push when app opened ? ,  Also your current code doesn't compile tried what in answer ?

Comment: In foreground, detect the remote notification in didRecieveRemoteNotification and send a local notification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting local notifications to show while app is in foreground Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713605/getting-local-notifications-to-show-while-app-is-in-foreground-swift-3)

Comment: Your question is not related to Firebase

Comment: @AntonBelousov I don't know why you say that, Firebase swizzle the user Notification Center methods to do their own logic so the answer to this question is 100% dependent on the context that firebase is being used!

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
@available(iOS 10, *)

    extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

          completionHandler([.alert, .sound])

    }

}
```

For more info check here [Notifications](http://www.thomashanning.com/push-notifications-local-notifications-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function, for push notification:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
     print("\(userInfo)")
}
```