# How to perform action on tap of Push Notification rather than performing action by itself when app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

currently I am using below-mentioned code

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void){
    completionHandler(.alert)
    let aps = notification.request.content.userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as! NSDictionary
    let alert = aps["alert"] as! String
    if alert == "Welcome to XYZ. To place order please click here"{
        let stryBrd = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = stryBrd.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")  as! viewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    }else{
        print("false")
    }
}
```

But in this code app is running automatically to desired view controller whereas I want it to happen only if a user taps on the notification.

Whereas it is working fine when an app is in the background. It's only happening if we are clicking on the notification

It should be the same as WhatsApp. When you are chatting with Mr ABC and miss PQR sends you a text then it will show push but won't do anything unless you tap on the push to open Miss PQR chat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting local notifications to show while app is in foreground Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713605/getting-local-notifications-to-show-while-app-is-in-foreground-swift-3)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713605/getting-local-notifications-to-show-while-app-is-in-foreground-swift-3

Comment: No, I am asking a different question. I am able to display my push but unable to perform action on tap. Right now if I am using my code then it's automatically migrating from current VC to desired where as I want it to happen only if user taps on Push

Comment: let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState to find the application state on will present

Comment: Need to do the same like whatsapp when you are chatting with Mr ABC and miss PQR sends you text then it will show push but won't do anything unless you tap on push to open Miss PQR chat

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIAlertController` to show push notification and on tap of button write the code to perform action

```
    let stryBrd = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = stryBrd.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")  as! viewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

More explanation:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void){
    completionHandler(.alert)
    let aps = notification.request.content.userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as! NSDictionary
    let alert = aps["alert"] as! String
    if alert == "Welcome to XYZ. To place order please click here"{

        //show alert to the user after getting push notification

        let myalert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        myalert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

            //perform action of push notification

            let stryBrd = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = stryBrd.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")  as! viewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        })
        myalert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            //handle cancel event
        })

        currentViewController.present(myalert, animated: true)
    }else{
        print("false")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arnab thanks for replying but showing pop up isn't an option here. Need to do the same like whatsapp when you are chatting with Mr ABC and miss PQR sends you text then it will show push but won't do anything unless you tap on push to open Miss PQR chat

Comment: then use custom view like whatsapp to show the text of push notification and add tap action to that view. On that tap action selector use the action to set rootViewController

Comment: Look at [this](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/14218787/15983592/e208537c-2fe7-11e6-85d5-55ce0abfc798.gif) and [this](https://github.com/trilliwon/JDropDownAlert) for more understanding

Comment: unable to open link. Access denied

Comment: search for `NotificationBanner in iOS` or `dropdown banner in iOS` in google