# Local Push Notification not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, push-notification

```
//
//  LocalNotifications.swift
//  PushNotifications_Tutorial
//
//  Created by Abhishek Gautam on 15/12/23.
//

import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

class NotificationManager {
    
    static let instance = NotificationManager() // Singleton
    
    func requestAuthorization() {
        
        let options : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound, .badge]
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { (success, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("ERROR : \(error)")
            }
            else {
                print("Success!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func scheduleNotification() {
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "This is my first push notification"
        content.subtitle = "This was sooooo much fun!"
        content.sound = .default
        content.badge = 1
        
        //time
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false)
        //calender
        //location
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
}

struct LocalNotifications: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing :40){
            Button("Request Permission") {
                NotificationManager.instance.requestAuthorization()
                //print("Button Tapped!")
            }
            Button("Schedule Notification") {
                NotificationManager.instance.scheduleNotification()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    LocalNotifications()
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but the problem is the notification is not showing up. I am trying to learn push notification in iOS from a youtube video, things seems to be working good for the youtuber, but I also did the same thing and it's not woking for me.

I tried to access the permission of the user, which is a Success. But when it comes to the pop-up part of the notification , it isn't showing up. Please help.

Comment: It looks like you wait for the notification to be displayed while the app is running in foreground. If so, here's relevant info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713605/getting-local-notifications-to-show-while-app-is-in-foreground-swift-3.

Comment: Try to set timeInterval to Date().timeIntervalSinceNow and append a few seconds by seconds * 60. Then go to the background and wait. I hope it helps.

Comment: @lazarevzubov i am trying to get it after minimizing the app, am i doing it correctly?

Comment: @son I tried using your method, but i am unable to get the desired output.Can this be a fault in the simulator ?

Comment: I have not tested it on a simulator, but I am pretty sure it will work on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

When app is background state and receives notification, the system displays the notification directly to the user. But in foreground state, the system delivers the notification to our app rather than displaying to the user.

To display notifications in foreground state or handle user interactions to the notification, we have to implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and the delegate must be set before the application returns from application(_:, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).

For details, please check Apple's documentations: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate

I fixed the issue by adding below code.

**Implement the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate with AppDelegate:**

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Set notification center delegate, otherwise delegate methods won't work
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // To receive notification in foreground state, you have to implement the completion hanlder properly, otherwise the notification will not be presented.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        print("willPresent:")

        completionHandler([.banner, .list, .badge, .sound])
    }

    // Handle user interactions to the notification
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        print("didReceive:")

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

**Add AppDelegate in SwiftUI App:**
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app

```
@main
struct NotificationApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

Comment: You can also add the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to the `NotificationManager`